# Can a robot that perceives the environment, conducts experiments, and writes OOP classes as its final result be considered AGI?

Tags: agi

In [my blog post](https://rashad.io/artificial-conceptual-intelligence), I provide the blueprint for "Artificial Conceptual Intelligence" (ACI), a type of robot that can:

- Perceive objects in the environment
- Manipulate the environment to obtain new perceptions
- Classify such objects into OOP classes

For instance, given a glass of water, an ice cube and a glass of alcohol, the robot:

- Perceives the three objects as separate from each other
- Manipulates them with experiments (such as to change their temperature)
- Writes OOP classes such that two of the objects belong to the OOP class Water, while the other belongs to the OOP class Alcohol.

Can this type of robot be considered an Artificial General Intelligence?

Note: I am using the definition of AGI used by this website, which states that it is: "a hypothetical machine characteristic permitting it to learn any arbitrary intellectual ability up to the limits of the available computing resources."

Comment: Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. The question needs to be more self-contained. Please don't rely on the link. Put a summary of the contents of the link in the body of the question, so that someone would not need to read the link to come to an initial opinion. In addition, put the main point of the question as the title, so that someone would not need to read the question to understand what expertise was required E.g. "Is an embodied robot that can navigate and converse and follow instructions an AGI?"

Comment: @NeilSlater Alright. Working on it.

Comment: Much better, thank you.

Comment: Please, reformulate the question so that it won't just lead to opinions.

Comment: @nbro I am not sure that it should lead to opinions. Whether anything is an AGI or not is not a matter of opinion. But if you can explain more why you think it should, I’ll take it into account.

Comment: I’m using the AGI definition used by this website which says: “a hypothetical machine characteristic permitting it to learn any arbitrary intellectual ability up to the limits of the available computing resources.”

Comment: @RashadSaleh It may lead to opinions because people use different definitions of AGI or not even use definitions but just intuitively think what an AGI may be or not.

Comment: @nbro OK I edited the question to explicitly point out which definition is being used. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Edited)

No, unless it self-learns mixing the ice with alcohol, offer it to someone, and invite to dance. Otherwise it is not 'general'.

To be precise, AGI needs to be able to (according to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence)):

```
1. reason, use strategy, solve puzzles, and make judgments under uncertainty;
2. represent knowledge, including common sense knowledge;
3. plan;
4. learn;
5. communicate in natural language;
6. if necessary, integrate these skills in completion of any given goal.
```

Now, take OP's case as example. What is missing (i.e. what can human do which this robot cannot)?

I'd say if this robot is truly AGI if it can:

1. Look at the table and understand what the 3 liquids are, and what they can be used for.
2. Learns how to make a cocktail out of them. If not enough ingredients, go buy some. (*solve puzzles, and make judgments under uncertainty*)
3. Make the cocktail.
4. Invite a lady to drink.
5. Flirt with the lady.
6. Invite the lady to dance, and dance.
7. Plan and execute all above-mention steps

These are all tasks we can (well, theoretically at least) do. OP's robot clearly cannot do some tasks:

1. it may learn how to, but cannot make the cocktail (but let's say that's fine by instructing others to);
2. cannot flirt (*communicate in natural language*) to get the lady to dance (*integrate skills in completion of given goal*).
3. Most importantly, we don't know if, given the goal 'dance with lady', it can draw this whole *plan* by itself.

We can build a cluster that holds all the OOPs in this world and make it write more OOPs alone, but that doesn't make it AGI as far as it doesn't know how to plan and achieve goals other than writing OOP.

Comment: It does self-learn which experiments to conduct and how to conduct them.

Comment: So it can only conduct experiment, nothing else.

Comment: As explained in the question, that's 1 of 3 things it does.

Comment: No I read it right, all it can do is to classify and write a summary. AGI requires doing *any intellectual task* that human can perform, which is more than that.

Comment: ACI excels at performing conceptual tasks. What intellectual tasks that are not conceptual are you thinking of?

Comment: 1.  reason, use strategy, solve puzzles, and make judgments under uncertainty;
   2.  represent knowledge, including common sense knowledge;
   3.  plan;
   4.  learn;
   5. communicate in natural language;
   6. integrate these skills in completion of any given goal.

Comment: directly from Wiki

Comment: All of these are conceptual tasks.

Comment: @NeilSlater good point, I expand my argument.

Comment: Thanks, the update works for me.